# IBQuery – при returning не найдет параметр

Tags: sql, delphi, firebird, interbase

Вот простой запрос на вставку, с возвратом "*ID*"

```
var
  q: integer;
begin
IBQuery1.Close;
IBQuery1.SQL.Clear;
IBQuery1.SQL.Text := 'insert into Tab (ID, STR) values (GEN_ID(GN, 1), :STR) returning ID';
IBQuery1.Params[0].AsString := 'qwe';
IBQuery1.Open;
IBTransaction1.CommitRetaining;
q := IBQuery1.Fields[0].Value;
```

но после его выполнения, не могу достучаться к возвращенному ID, на строке "*q := IBQuery1.Fields[0].Value;*" ошибка:

> 'IBQuery1: List index out of bounds (0)'.

Что не так?

P.S.
- FireBird 3.0

Comment: дело в том, что в IBExpert запрос работает, добавляет запись и выдает "*ID*". Тут дело может быть в самом "*IBQuery*"?

Comment: Вычитал, что версии компонентов доступа к серверу - IBX могут не поддерживать эту особенность, а где можно посмотреть версию IBX, которую я использую?

Comment: До коммита попробуй

Comment: В обсуждении похожего вопроса пишут, что IBQuery не поддерживает Returning https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574730/firebird-tibquery-insert-with-returning-into